# a child form that runs a function when called

Tags: c#, forms, serial-port

I open a second form from my first form using Form1.ShowDialog(). I want to run the dataset() function continuously. when i call it in load function and loop it, my form does not load. I just want to load the form and loop the function 'dataset()'. This is my complete file. I am also calling the serialport here from form 1.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{

    public partial class popupMenu : Form
    {
        InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
        int x_base, y_base = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        private const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
        public popupMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Form1 parentForm;

        public popupMenu(Form1 parentForm)
        {
            this.parentForm = parentForm;
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void popupMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
            int check = Convert.ToInt32(0.02 * (workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height));
            this.Top = workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height - check;

            dataset();

        }

        public void dataset()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                String data = parentForm.serialPort1.ReadLine();
                int[] data_received = Array.ConvertAll(data.Split(','), s => int.Parse(s));
                if (counter == 0)
                {
                    x_base = data_received[0];
                    y_base = data_received[1];
                    counter = 1;
                }

                data_received[0] = data_received[0] - x_base;
                data_received[1] = data_received[1] - y_base;

                if (x > data_received[0])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X value:{0}, Y value:{1}", data_received[0], data_received[1]);
                    sim.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RIGHT);
                }
                x = data_received[0];
                y = data_received[1];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your form does not load because your thread stay stucked in your `while (true)` loop.

Comment: Running a `while (true)` loop is always a bad idea. Running it from the UI thread is even worse, since you are then preventing this same (single) UI thread from painting controls. Making the `serialPort` of the parent form a public field which anybody can access at will is also a bad idea. Apart from that, your code doesn't even show where you call this function, so you should also post a [mcve].

Comment: Where do you open the dialog ? this code here seems irrelevant to the question.

Comment: my apologies, ive updated the code to include where i call my function. how should i go about solving this problem